# aws lambda api gatewayc AmazonDynamoDBException

Tags: asp.net-core, aws-lambda

My app is in AWS using c# .net core.
I have lambda api **which was working before** I explored to add cloudfront and added another user. Now it is no longer working and I don't have any idea how to fix (I am just new in aws, was just able to up all of it through video tutorial I watched). So, to isolate, I deleted the cloudfront distributions I just created as it may be the cause, but it still wont work, I also deleted the user as the error is hinting it may be looking for a "shared credentials", but still didn't work. My api is working in local, and performing CRUD to dynamodb directly so I know that there's no problem with my dynamodb and my aws access configuration. It only breaks when it's deployed.

**UPDATE** my lambdas has

**LambdaDynamoDBRole - DynamoReadWriteAccess**

while we are at it, I am not sure if it is even correct to point to my local folder, I didn't notice it before when it was still working, but I didn't modify in my config that will point it to local o r not, but below is an excerpt.

```
at AWSServerlessPOS.Services.CategoryListService.ScanAsync(QueryRequest request) in C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\AWSServerlessPOS\AWSServerlessPOS\Services\CategoryListService.cs:line 65
```

here is the image oy my swagger error:

[image]

below is the entire error log I took from cloudwatch after calling the GET of my api:

```
[Error] Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.AbstractAspNetCoreFunction: Unknown error responding to request: AmazonDynamoDBException:
Amazon.DynamoDBv2.AmazonDynamoDBException: The security token included in the request is invalid
 ---> Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException: Exception of type 'Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException' was thrown.
   at Amazon.Runtime.HttpWebRequestMessage.GetResponseAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpHandler`1.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Unmarshaller.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseExceptionHandler.HandleException(IExecutionContext executionContext, HttpErrorResponseException exception)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ExceptionHandler`1.Handle(IExecutionContext executionContext, Exception exception)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.ProcessException(IExecutionContext executionContext, Exception exception)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointDiscoveryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointDiscoveryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CredentialsRetriever.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at AWSServerlessPOS.Services.CategoryListService.ScanAsync(QueryRequest request) in C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\AWSServerlessPOS\AWSServerlessPOS\Services\CategoryListService.cs:line 65
   at AWSServerlessPOS.Services.CategoryListService.GetItems(String id) in C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\AWSServerlessPOS\AWSServerlessPOS\Services\CategoryListService.cs:line 33
   at AWSServerlessPOS.Controllers.CategoryListController.GetItems(String id) in C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\AWSServerlessPOS\AWSServerlessPOS\Controllers\CategoryListController.cs:line 35
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.AbstractAspNetCoreFunction`2.ProcessRequest(ILambdaContext lambdaContext, Object context, InvokeFeatures features, Boolean rethrowUnhandledError)
AmazonDynamoDBException:
Amazon.DynamoDBv2.AmazonDynamoDBException: The security token included in the request is invalid
 ---> Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException: Exception of type 'Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException' was thrown.
   at Amazon.Runtime.HttpWebRequestMessage.GetResponseAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpHandler`1.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Unmarshaller.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseExceptionHandler.HandleException(IExecutionContext executionContext, HttpErrorResponseException exception)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ExceptionHandler`1.Handle(IExecutionContext executionContext, Exception exception)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.ProcessException(IExecutionContext executionContext, Exception exception)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointDiscoveryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointDiscoveryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CredentialsRetriever.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at AWSServerlessPOS.Services.CategoryListService.ScanAsync(QueryRequest request) in C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\AWSServerlessPOS\AWSServerlessPOS\Services\CategoryListService.cs:line 65
   at AWSServerlessPOS.Services.CategoryListService.GetItems(String id) in C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\AWSServerlessPOS\AWSServerlessPOS\Services\CategoryListService.cs:line 33
   at AWSServerlessPOS.Controllers.CategoryListController.GetItems(String id) in C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\AWSServerlessPOS\AWSServerlessPOS\Controllers\CategoryListController.cs:line 35
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.AbstractAspNetCoreFunction`2.ProcessRequest(ILambdaContext lambdaContext, Object context, InvokeFeatures features, Boolean rethrowUnhandledError)
HttpErrorResponseException:
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException: Exception of type 'Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException' was thrown.
   at Amazon.Runtime.HttpWebRequestMessage.GetResponseAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpHandler`1.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Unmarshaller.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
```

any idea how I can fix this? thanks

Comment: Can you check if your lambda execution role is having dynamodb access? Dynamodb exception is complaining about security token. So looks like permission issue.

Comment: Yes, it has LambdaDynamoDBRole - DynamoReadWriteAccess . sorry I forgot to mention.

Comment: Can you provide the code of your function?

Answer (score 0):

If it is working from your local, I would assume you might have hardcoded the AWS credentials in the code using one of the AWSCredentials classes. e.g.

`new Amazon.Runtime.BasicAWSCredentials("","")`

If it is the case, remove any hardcoded credentials.

`at AWSServerlessPOS.Services.CategoryListService.ScanAsync(QueryRequest request) in C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\AWSServerlessPOS\AWSServerlessPOS\Services\CategoryListService.cs:line 65`

The above line should not come on AWS, unless you are using a custom runtime for your Lambda. The default runtime for `C#` are Linux based and definitely they would not be having a Windows path system. Without access to the full code, I would assume some hardcoding causing this issue as well.